# Update new apk with new apk without losing data and also update the version

Tags: android, sqlite, apk, maui, app-update

Whenever I introduce new functionalities to my **.NET MAUI app** and create a new **APK**, I aim to seamlessly update the existing installations on users' devices without losing any of their data. This means that when users install the updated version of the app, they shouldn't experience any loss or corruption of their previously saved data.

To achieve this, I need a solution that ensures a smooth transition from the old version to the new one, without causing any disruptions to the user experience. Since I'm utilizing an SQLite database for storing app data, the database must remain intact during the update process.

However, when I attempt to install the new **APK** over an existing installation on a device where the older version is already present, I encounter an `"App not installed"` error. This error indicates that there might be an issue with the package, preventing it from being installed properly.

```
Error: App not installed as package appears to be invalid
```

I tried to get the solution over the Internet but did not get any resolution

Comment: If the app does not allow to be installed as update the APK signature signing key is different. Usually for apps that have been added to Play Store in the last few years Google manages the signature keys. In that case a local build can not be used to update an app version installed via Google Play as you don't have the real signing keys. Not sure if it is possible to retrieve the signing keys Google have created. If you want to test app migration you have to use local builds for the old and the new version.